# Schema verification using the hash from table-structure. SQLite

Tags: sqlite, database-schema

In a changing application I want to verify, that the expected schema is indeed the schema of the DB.

First I've stored a schema version in an additional meta-table, but forgot to update this version sometimes when the schema changed.

Now I'm considering to generate a hash value of the schema (simple concatination of all tablenames and column names should suffice) and store it as the version.

Would it work? Is there an easier way, in particular for SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite databases have an internal [file change counter](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#chngctr) to be able to detect changes made by other processes, but this applies to all changes. There is no mechanism for schema changes.

Storing a hash of the schema would work.
Please note that the easiest way to do this would be to hash the contents of the `sql` column of the [`sqlite_master` table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master), properly sorted.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the links! I was not aware of this features in SQLite